# i'm trying to dump user details (from phpmyadmin database) onto my browser but getting an error code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Error message:

> Db connection successful Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member
>   function execute() on bool in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/tennisdaily/app/database/db.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tennisdaily/app/database/db.php on
>   line 9

db.php:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$users = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo "<pre>" , print_r($users). "</pre>";
```

connect.php:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = "";
$db_name = "tennisdaily";

$conn = new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error){
die('Database connection error: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
else {
echo "Db connection successful";
}

?>
```

Comment: add your connect.php code into your question

Comment: Apologies, I have now added the connect.php code @MUFAzmi

Comment: Please add your attempts to resolve the problem to the question